# sql Максимальное значение по группе

Tags: sql

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Саша |
| 2 | Миша |

| id | date | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | РФ |
| 1 | 01.02.2021 | США |
| 2 | 01.03.2021 | РФ |
| 2 | 01.02.2021 | Перу |

Привет! Есть две таблицы, юзер и его входы в систему. Нужно составить запрос, который будет показывать страну последнего входа по каждому юзеру.

Я посчитал максимальное значение даты, как последнее и вывел имя пользователя, но страну добавить не получается в лоб - она не входит в группировку. Я так понимаю нужен подзапрос но не понимаю как его вкрутить.

```
SELECT t1.name, MAX(t2.date)
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Comment: row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) as rn и в CTE выбирая с rn=1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name,b.country FROM 
(SELECT t1.name,t1.id, MAX(t2.date) as maxd FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id GROUP BY t1.name) as a, t2 as b 
WHERE b.id=a.id AND a.maxd=b.date
```

ваш подзапрос практически без изменений, обернут еще связями с исходной таблицей t2. Еще можно было не джойнить таблицу t1 в группируемом подзапросе, а приджойнить потом. Например, так

```
SELECT t1.name,b.country FROM 
(SELECT t2.id, MAX(t2.date) as maxd FROM t2 GROUP BY t2.id) as a, 
t2 as b, t1 
WHERE b.id=a.id AND t1.id=a.id and a.maxd=b.date
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вы забыли добавить в группировку t1.id. И DATE стоит взять в кавычки, т.к. это служебное слово и так просто столбец таким словом не обозвать.

Comment: я тестил запрос в mysql, там все нормально

Comment: По поводу группировки сейчас думаю, достаточно только по t1.id группировать, хотя связь t1.id c t1.name однозначная..зачем группировать по двум полям я не совсем понимаю. может что-то не догоняю..но запрос нормально отработал в mysql локально.

Comment: На самом деле действительно не работает, пишет Column 't1.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Если добавить группировку, то работает, но почему-то через jony, группируя по стране в том числе. Не понимаю почему так, на глаз запрос правильный, я о том же способе думал, что и у вас.

Comment: проверил еще раз, запрос именно в таком виде отрабатывает успешно. База только не mysql оказывается у меня локально, а 10.4.17-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution. Ответвление от mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Запускалось в Oracle. После группировки повторно джойнимся на себя.

```
with
  t1 as (
    SELECT 1 id, 'Саша' name from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 id, 'Миша' name from dual
  ),
  t2 as (
    SELECT 1 id, DATE '2021-01-01' "DATE", 'РФ'   country from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 id, DATE '2021-02-01' "DATE", 'США'  country from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 id, DATE '2021-03-01' "DATE", 'РФ'   country from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 id, DATE '2021-02-01' "DATE", 'Перу' country from dual
  )
SELECT a.name
     , t2.country
  FROM (  SELECT t1.name
               , t1.id
               , MAX(t2."DATE") AS maxd
            FROM t1
               , t2
           WHERE t1.id = t2.id
        GROUP BY t1.name
               , t1.id) a
     , t2
 WHERE t2.id = a.id
   AND t2."DATE" = a.maxd;
```

Comment: Ответ в стиле автора, хотя я уже отвык от отсутствия прямого указания JOIN'ов.